# Unable to create AWS EKS cluster and worker nodes group by a single AWS CloudFormation stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-eks

I want to setup AWS EKS cluster (AWS::EKS::Cluster) and worker nodes group (AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup) in a single CloudFormation stack. This is the CF definition I created:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"

Description: Creates API gateway and services for my projects

Parameters:

  ClusterName:
    Type: String
    Description: Cluster name
    Default: eks-min-cluster

  NodeAutoScalingGroupDesiredCapacity:
    Type: Number
    Default: 2
    Description: Desired capacity of Node Group ASG.

  NodeAutoScalingGroupMinSize:
    Type: Number
    Default: 1
    Description: Minimum size of Node Group ASG.

  NodeAutoScalingGroupMaxSize:
    Type: Number
    Default: 3
    Description: Maximum size of Node Group ASG. Set to at least 1 greater than NodeAutoScalingGroupDesiredCapacity.

  BootstrapArguments:
    Type: String
    Default: ""
    Description: "Arguments to pass to the nodes' bootstrap script. See files/bootstrap.sh in https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-eks-ami"

  VpcCidr:
    Description: Please enter the IP range (CIDR notation) for this VPC
    Type: String
    Default: 10.192.0.0/16

  PublicSubnet1Cidr:
    Description: Please enter the IP range (CIDR notation) for the public subnet in the first Availability Zone
    Type: String
    Default: 10.192.20.0/24

  PublicSubnet2Cidr:
    Description: Please enter the IP range (CIDR notation) for the public subnet in the first Availability Zone
    Type: String
    Default: 10.192.21.0/24

  PrivateSubnet1Cidr:
    Description: Please enter the IP range (CIDR notation) for the private subnet in the first Availability Zone
    Type: String
    Default: 10.192.22.0/24

  PrivateSubnet2Cidr:
    Description: Please enter the IP range (CIDR notation) for the private subnet in the second Availability Zone
    Type: String
    Default: 10.192.23.0/24

  NodeImageIdSSMParam:
    Type: "AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<AWS::EC2::Image::Id>"
    Default: /aws/service/eks/optimized-ami/1.14/amazon-linux-2/recommended/image_id
    Description: AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store parameter of the AMI ID for the worker node instances.

Resources: 

  InternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway

  Vpc:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: !Ref VpcCidr
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      EnableDnsHostnames: true

  VpcGatewayAttachment:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties: 
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc

  PublicSubnet1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 0, !GetAZs  '' ]
      CidrBlock: !Ref PublicSubnet1Cidr
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true

  PublicSubnet2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 1, !GetAZs  '' ]
      CidrBlock: !Ref PublicSubnet2Cidr
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true

  PrivateSubnet1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 0, !GetAZs  '' ]
      CidrBlock: !Ref PrivateSubnet1Cidr
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true

  PrivateSubnet2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 1, !GetAZs  '' ]
      CidrBlock: !Ref PrivateSubnet2Cidr
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true

  SshSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
      GroupDescription: Enable SSH access via port 22
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          FromPort: 22
          IpProtocol: tcp
          ToPort: 22
        - CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          FromPort: 8
          IpProtocol: icmp
          ToPort: -1

  GatewayHostSshPortAddress:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    DependsOn: VpcGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc

  AssociateGatewayHostSshPort:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIPAssociation
    DependsOn: GatewayHostSshPortAddress
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt GatewayHostSshPortAddress.AllocationId
      NetworkInterfaceId: !Ref GatewayHostSshNetworkInterface

  GatewayHostSshNetworkInterface:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet1
      Description: Interface for controlling traffic such as SSH
      GroupSet: 
        - !Ref SshSecurityGroup
      SourceDestCheck: true

  PublicRouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc

  PrivateSubnet1RouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc

  PrivateSubnet2RouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc

  DefaultPublicRoute:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn: VpcGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway

  PrivateSubnet1Route:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn:
      - VpcGatewayAttachment
      - PrivateSubnet1NatGateway
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateSubnet1RouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      NatGatewayId: !Ref PrivateSubnet1NatGateway

  PrivateSubnet2Route:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn:
      - VpcGatewayAttachment
      - PrivateSubnet2NatGateway
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateSubnet2RouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      NatGatewayId: !Ref PrivateSubnet2NatGateway

  PrivateSubnet1NatGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NatGateway
    DependsOn:
      - PrivateSubnet1NatGatewayEIP
      - PublicSubnet1
      - VpcGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt PrivateSubnet1NatGatewayEIP.AllocationId
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet1

  PrivateSubnet2NatGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NatGateway
    DependsOn:
      - PrivateSubnet2NatGatewayEIP
      - PublicSubnet2
      - VpcGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt PrivateSubnet2NatGatewayEIP.AllocationId
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet2

  PrivateSubnet1NatGatewayEIP:
    DependsOn:
    - VpcGatewayAttachment
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::EIP'
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc

  PrivateSubnet2NatGatewayEIP:
    DependsOn:
    - VpcGatewayAttachment
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::EIP'
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc

  PublicRouteTableToPublicSubnet1Association:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet1

  PublicRouteTableToPublicSubnet2Association:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet2

  PrivateRouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc


  GatewayHost:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    DependsOn: [AssociateGatewayHostSshPort]
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-03c3a7e4263fd998c
      InstanceType: t2.nano
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 0, !GetAZs  '' ]
      KeyName: jd-system
      NetworkInterfaces:
        -
          NetworkInterfaceId: !Ref GatewayHostSshNetworkInterface
          DeviceIndex: 0
    Metadata: 
      AWS::CloudFormation::Init: 
        config: 
          files: 
            /etc/kong/kong.yml: 
              content: test-jd
              #source: 
              mode: "000644"
              owner: "root"
              group: "root"

  EksIamRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - eks.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      RoleName: EksIamRole
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSClusterPolicy
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSServicePolicy



################### CONTROL PLANE ###################

  ClusterControlPlaneSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Cluster communication with worker nodes
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc

  EksCluster:
    Type: AWS::EKS::Cluster
    Properties:
      Name: !Ref ClusterName
      RoleArn: !GetAtt EksIamRole.Arn
      ResourcesVpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - !Ref SshSecurityGroup
          - !Ref ClusterControlPlaneSecurityGroup
        SubnetIds:
          - !Ref PublicSubnet1
          - !Ref PublicSubnet2
          - !Ref PrivateSubnet1
          - !Ref PrivateSubnet2
    DependsOn: [EksIamRole, PublicSubnet1, PublicSubnet2, PrivateSubnet1, PrivateSubnet2, SshSecurityGroup]

################### WORKER NODES ###################


  NodeSecurityGroup:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup"
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Security group for all nodes in the cluster
      Tags:
        - Key: !Sub kubernetes.io/cluster/${ClusterName}
          Value: owned
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc

  NodeSecurityGroupIngress:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress"
    DependsOn: NodeSecurityGroup
    Properties:
      Description: Allow node to communicate with each other
      FromPort: 0
      GroupId: !Ref NodeSecurityGroup
      IpProtocol: "-1"
      SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref NodeSecurityGroup
      ToPort: 65535

  ClusterControlPlaneSecurityGroupIngress:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress"
    DependsOn: NodeSecurityGroup
    Properties:
      Description: Allow pods to communicate with the cluster API Server
      FromPort: 443
      GroupId: !Ref ClusterControlPlaneSecurityGroup
      IpProtocol: tcp
      SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref NodeSecurityGroup
      ToPort: 443

  ControlPlaneEgressToNodeSecurityGroup:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupEgress"
    DependsOn: NodeSecurityGroup
    Properties:
      Description: Allow the cluster control plane to communicate with worker Kubelet and pods
      DestinationSecurityGroupId: !Ref NodeSecurityGroup
      FromPort: 1025
      GroupId: !Ref ClusterControlPlaneSecurityGroup
      IpProtocol: tcp
      ToPort: 65535

  ControlPlaneEgressToNodeSecurityGroupOn443:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupEgress"
    DependsOn: NodeSecurityGroup
    Properties:
      Description: Allow the cluster control plane to communicate with pods running extension API servers on port 443
      DestinationSecurityGroupId: !Ref NodeSecurityGroup
      FromPort: 443
      GroupId: !Ref ClusterControlPlaneSecurityGroup
      IpProtocol: tcp
      ToPort: 443

  NodeSecurityGroupFromControlPlaneIngress:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress"
    DependsOn: NodeSecurityGroup
    Properties:
      Description: Allow worker Kubelets and pods to receive communication from the cluster control plane
      FromPort: 1025
      GroupId: !Ref NodeSecurityGroup
      IpProtocol: tcp
      SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref ClusterControlPlaneSecurityGroup
      ToPort: 65535

  NodeSecurityGroupFromControlPlaneOn443Ingress:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress"
    DependsOn: NodeSecurityGroup
    Properties:
      Description: Allow pods running extension API servers on port 443 to receive communication from cluster control plane
      FromPort: 443
      GroupId: !Ref NodeSecurityGroup
      IpProtocol: tcp
      SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref ClusterControlPlaneSecurityGroup
      ToPort: 443

  NodeInstanceRole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ec2.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - "sts:AssumeRole"
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy"
        - "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy"
        - "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly"
      Path: /

  NodeInstanceProfile:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile"
    Properties:
      Path: /
      Roles:
        - Ref: NodeInstanceRole

  NodeLaunchConfig:
    Type: "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration"
    Properties:
      AssociatePublicIpAddress: "true"
      BlockDeviceMappings:
        - DeviceName: /dev/xvda
          Ebs:
            DeleteOnTermination: true
            VolumeSize: 10
            VolumeType: gp2
      IamInstanceProfile: !Ref NodeInstanceProfile
      #ImageId: ami-03c3a7e4263fd998c
      ImageId: !Ref NodeImageIdSSMParam
      InstanceType: t2.nano
      KeyName: jd-system
      SecurityGroups:
        - Ref: NodeSecurityGroup
      UserData: !Base64
        "Fn::Sub": |
          #!/bin/bash
          set -o xtrace
          /etc/eks/bootstrap.sh ${ClusterName} ${BootstrapArguments}
          /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal --exit-code $? \
                   --stack  ${AWS::StackName} \
                   --resource NodeGroup  \
                   --region ${AWS::Region}

  NodeGroup:
    Type: "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup"
    DependsOn: 
      - EksCluster
      - Vpc
    Properties:
      DesiredCapacity: !Ref NodeAutoScalingGroupDesiredCapacity
      LaunchConfigurationName: !Ref NodeLaunchConfig
      MaxSize: !Ref NodeAutoScalingGroupMaxSize
      MinSize: !Ref NodeAutoScalingGroupMinSize
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          PropagateAtLaunch: "true"
          Value: !Sub ${ClusterName}-NodeGroup-Node
        - Key: !Sub kubernetes.io/cluster/${ClusterName}
          PropagateAtLaunch: "true"
          Value: owned
      VPCZoneIdentifier: 
        - !Ref PublicSubnet1
        - !Ref PublicSubnet2
        - !Ref PrivateSubnet1
        - !Ref PrivateSubnet2
    UpdatePolicy:
      AutoScalingRollingUpdate:
        MaxBatchSize: "1"
        MinInstancesInService: !Ref NodeAutoScalingGroupDesiredCapacity
        PauseTime: PT5M

Outputs:
  GatewayHostPublicIp:
    Description: Gateway host public ip
    Value: !GetAtt GatewayHost.PublicIp
  EksClusterEndpoint:
    Description: EksCluster endpoint
    Value: !GetAtt EksCluster.Endpoint
```

After stack creation I cannot see any worker nodes:

```
$ kubectl get nodes
No resources found
```

Nor pods are getting created:

```
$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   coredns-59b69b4849-l97bq          0/1     Pending   0          7m15s
kube-system   coredns-59b69b4849-zwtql          0/1     Pending   0          7m15s
kube-system   metrics-server-7949d47784-2xjck   0/1     Pending   0          8s
```

Tutorials I read create EKS cluster via one CF stack and worker nodes group via another. I want to setup everything via single script. I suspect that the worker nodes group is getting created too quickly, however, I am new to CF and EKS and cannot confirm that. Please advise.

Comment: The template gets deployed without any issues?

Comment: Yes, the template gets deployed and stack gets created successfully. I am able to SSH to 'testing' EC2 instance 'GatewayHost'. But the worker nodes are not getting created.

Comment: The nodes also don't show in EC2 console? Or they get created but do not register with the cluster?

Comment: I cann see the nodes in EC2 console (did not think of checking that later) but still they are not getting registered with the cluster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to **reproduce** the error and I modified your template for my tests. The template modified is below, so you have to check it if you want. Also you would have to adjust it to your setup if you want to use it. For simplicity I put everything in public subnets, but I don't think it is the key issue here.

I think the core issue is that you are **not setting up** `aws-auth-cm.yaml` which prohibits the node instances to register with the cluster.

To **setup** `aws-auth-cm.yaml` please have a look at [To enable nodes to join your cluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/launch-workers.html) section. Once I did it, I could see my node in `kubectl get nodes` when using the template below.

I have `kubectl` running on my local workstation, not on the bastion host that you create. I only tested nodes joining cluster, not the functionality of any pods. Also EKS AWS console does not show the nodes, but `kubectl get nodes` shows them.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"

Description: Creates API gateway and services for my projects

Parameters:

  ClusterName:
    Type: String
    Description: Cluster name
    Default: eks-min-cluster

  NodeAutoScalingGroupDesiredCapacity:
    Type: Number
    Default: 1
    Description: Desired capacity of Node Group ASG.

  NodeAutoScalingGroupMinSize:
    Type: Number
    Default: 1
    Description: Minimum size of Node Group ASG.

  KeyPair:
    Type: AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName
    Default: jd-system

  NodeAutoScalingGroupMaxSize:
    Type: Number
    Default: 3
    Description: Maximum size of Node Group ASG. Set to at least 1 greater than NodeAutoScalingGroupDesiredCapacity.

  BootstrapArguments:
    Type: String
    Default: ""
    Description: "Arguments to pass to the nodes' bootstrap script. See files/bootstrap.sh in https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-eks-ami"

  VpcCidr:
    Description: Please enter the IP range (CIDR notation) for this VPC
    Type: String
    Default: 10.192.0.0/16

  PublicSubnet1Cidr:
    Description: Please enter the IP range (CIDR notation) for the public subnet in the first Availability Zone
    Type: String
    Default: 10.192.20.0/24

  PublicSubnet2Cidr:
    Description: Please enter the IP range (CIDR notation) for the public subnet in the first Availability Zone
    Type: String
    Default: 10.192.21.0/24

  PrivateSubnet1Cidr:
    Description: Please enter the IP range (CIDR notation) for the private subnet in the first Availability Zone
    Type: String
    Default: 10.192.22.0/24

  PrivateSubnet2Cidr:
    Description: Please enter the IP range (CIDR notation) for the private subnet in the second Availability Zone
    Type: String
    Default: 10.192.23.0/24

  NodeImageIdSSMParam:
    Type: "AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<AWS::EC2::Image::Id>"
    Default: /aws/service/eks/optimized-ami/1.18/amazon-linux-2/recommended/image_id
    Description: AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store parameter of the AMI ID for the worker node instances.

  LatestAmiId:
    Type: 'AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<AWS::EC2::Image::Id>'
    Default: '/aws/service/ami-amazon-linux-latest/amzn2-ami-hvm-x86_64-gp2'


Resources: 

  InternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway

  Vpc:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: !Ref VpcCidr
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      Tags:
       - Key: !Sub "kubernetes.io/cluster/${ClusterName}"
         Value: shared           
       - Key: Name
         Value: MyEksVpc      

  VpcGatewayAttachment:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties: 
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc

  PublicSubnet1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 0, !GetAZs  '' ]
      CidrBlock: !Ref PublicSubnet1Cidr
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
      Tags:
       - Key: kubernetes.io/role/elb
         Value: 1    
      Tags:
       - Key: !Sub "kubernetes.io/cluster/${ClusterName}"
         Value: shared

  PublicSubnet2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 1, !GetAZs  '' ]
      CidrBlock: !Ref PublicSubnet2Cidr
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
      Tags:
       - Key: kubernetes.io/role/elb
         Value: 1            
       - Key: !Sub "kubernetes.io/cluster/${ClusterName}"
         Value: shared      

  PrivateSubnet1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 0, !GetAZs  '' ]
      CidrBlock: !Ref PrivateSubnet1Cidr
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
      Tags:
       - Key: kubernetes.io/role/internal-elb
         Value: 1    

  PrivateSubnet2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 1, !GetAZs  '' ]
      CidrBlock: !Ref PrivateSubnet2Cidr
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
      Tags:
       - Key: kubernetes.io/role/internal-elb
         Value: 1         

  SshSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
      GroupDescription: Enable SSH access via port 22
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          FromPort: 22
          IpProtocol: tcp
          ToPort: 22
        - CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          FromPort: 8
          IpProtocol: icmp
          ToPort: -1

  GatewayHostSshPortAddress:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    DependsOn: VpcGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc

  AssociateGatewayHostSshPort:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIPAssociation
    DependsOn: GatewayHostSshPortAddress
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt GatewayHostSshPortAddress.AllocationId
      NetworkInterfaceId: !Ref GatewayHostSshNetworkInterface

  GatewayHostSshNetworkInterface:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet1
      Description: Interface for controlling traffic such as SSH
      GroupSet: 
        - !Ref SshSecurityGroup
      SourceDestCheck: true

  PublicRouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc

  PrivateSubnet1RouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc

  PrivateSubnet2RouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc

  DefaultPublicRoute:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    #DependsOn: VpcGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway

  PrivateSubnet1Route:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    #DependsOn:
    #  - VpcGatewayAttachment
    #  - PrivateSubnet1NatGateway
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateSubnet1RouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      NatGatewayId: !Ref PrivateSubnet1NatGateway

  PrivateSubnet2Route:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    #DependsOn:
    #  - VpcGatewayAttachment
    #  - PrivateSubnet2NatGateway
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateSubnet2RouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      NatGatewayId: !Ref PrivateSubnet2NatGateway

  PrivateSubnet1NatGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NatGateway
    #DependsOn:
    #  - PrivateSubnet1NatGatewayEIP
      #- PublicSubnet1
      #- VpcGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt PrivateSubnet1NatGatewayEIP.AllocationId
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet1

  PrivateSubnet2NatGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NatGateway
    # DependsOn:
    #   - PrivateSubnet2NatGatewayEIP
    #   - PublicSubnet2
    #   - VpcGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      AllocationId: !GetAtt PrivateSubnet2NatGatewayEIP.AllocationId
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet2

  PrivateSubnet1NatGatewayEIP:
    DependsOn:
    - VpcGatewayAttachment
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::EIP'
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc

  PrivateSubnet2NatGatewayEIP:
    DependsOn:
    - VpcGatewayAttachment
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::EIP'
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc

  PublicRouteTableToPublicSubnet1Association:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet1

  PublicRouteTableToPublicSubnet2Association:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PublicRouteTable
      SubnetId: !Ref PublicSubnet2

  PrivateRouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc


#   GatewayHost:
#     Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
#     DependsOn: [AssociateGatewayHostSshPort]
#     Properties:
#       ImageId:  !Ref LatestAmiId
#       InstanceType: t2.nano
#       AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 0, !GetAZs  '' ]
#       KeyName: !Ref KeyPair
#       NetworkInterfaces:
#         -
#           NetworkInterfaceId: !Ref GatewayHostSshNetworkInterface
#           DeviceIndex: 0
#     # Metadata: 
#     #   AWS::CloudFormation::Init: 
#     #     config: 
#     #       files: 
#     #         /etc/kong/kong.yml: 
#     #           content: test-jd
#     #           #source: 
#     #           mode: "000644"
#     #           owner: "root"
#     #           group: "root"

  EksIamRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - eks.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      #RoleName: EksIamRole
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSClusterPolicy
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSServicePolicy



################### CONTROL PLANE ###################

  ClusterControlPlaneSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Cluster communication with worker nodes
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc

  EksCluster:
    Type: AWS::EKS::Cluster
    Properties:
      Name: !Ref ClusterName
      RoleArn: !GetAtt EksIamRole.Arn
      ResourcesVpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          #- !Ref SshSecurityGroup
          - !Ref ClusterControlPlaneSecurityGroup
        SubnetIds:
          - !Ref PublicSubnet1
          - !Ref PublicSubnet2
          #- !Ref PrivateSubnet1
          #- !Ref PrivateSubnet2
    #DependsOn: [EksIamRole, PublicSubnet1, PublicSubnet2, PrivateSubnet1, PrivateSubnet2, SshSecurityGroup]

################### WORKER NODES ###################


  NodeSecurityGroup:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup"
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Security group for all nodes in the cluster
      Tags:
        - Key: !Sub kubernetes.io/cluster/${ClusterName}
          Value: owned
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc

  NodeSecurityGroupIngress:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress"
    DependsOn: NodeSecurityGroup
    Properties:
      Description: Allow node to communicate with each other
      FromPort: 0
      GroupId: !Ref NodeSecurityGroup
      IpProtocol: "-1"
      SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref NodeSecurityGroup
      ToPort: 65535

  ClusterControlPlaneSecurityGroupIngress:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress"
    #DependsOn: NodeSecurityGroup
    Properties:
      Description: Allow pods to communicate with the cluster API Server
      FromPort: 443
      GroupId: !Ref ClusterControlPlaneSecurityGroup
      IpProtocol: tcp
      SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref NodeSecurityGroup
      ToPort: 443

  ControlPlaneEgressToNodeSecurityGroup:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupEgress"
    #DependsOn: NodeSecurityGroup
    Properties:
      Description: Allow the cluster control plane to communicate with worker Kubelet and pods
      DestinationSecurityGroupId: !Ref NodeSecurityGroup
      FromPort: 1025
      GroupId: !Ref ClusterControlPlaneSecurityGroup
      IpProtocol: tcp
      ToPort: 65535

  ControlPlaneEgressToNodeSecurityGroupOn443:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupEgress"
    #DependsOn: NodeSecurityGroup
    Properties:
      Description: Allow the cluster control plane to communicate with pods running extension API servers on port 443
      DestinationSecurityGroupId: !Ref NodeSecurityGroup
      FromPort: 443
      GroupId: !Ref ClusterControlPlaneSecurityGroup
      IpProtocol: tcp
      ToPort: 443

  NodeSecurityGroupFromControlPlaneIngress:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress"
    #DependsOn: NodeSecurityGroup
    Properties:
      Description: Allow worker Kubelets and pods to receive communication from the cluster control plane
      FromPort: 1025
      GroupId: !Ref NodeSecurityGroup
      IpProtocol: tcp
      SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref ClusterControlPlaneSecurityGroup
      ToPort: 65535

  NodeSecurityGroupFromControlPlaneOn443Ingress:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress"
    #DependsOn: NodeSecurityGroup
    Properties:
      Description: Allow pods running extension API servers on port 443 to receive communication from cluster control plane
      FromPort: 443
      GroupId: !Ref NodeSecurityGroup
      IpProtocol: tcp
      SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref ClusterControlPlaneSecurityGroup
      ToPort: 443

  NodeInstanceRole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ec2.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - "sts:AssumeRole"
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy"
        - "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy"
        - "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly"
      Path: /

  NodeInstanceProfile:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile"
    Properties:
      Path: /
      Roles:
        - Ref: NodeInstanceRole

  NodeLaunchConfig:
    Type: "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration"
    Properties:
      AssociatePublicIpAddress: "true"
      BlockDeviceMappings:
        - DeviceName: /dev/xvda
          Ebs:
            DeleteOnTermination: true
            VolumeSize: 20
            VolumeType: gp2
      IamInstanceProfile: !Ref NodeInstanceProfile
      #ImageId: ami-03c3a7e4263fd998c
      ImageId: !Ref NodeImageIdSSMParam
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      KeyName: !Ref KeyPair
      SecurityGroups:
        - Ref: NodeSecurityGroup
      UserData: !Base64
        "Fn::Sub": |
          #!/bin/bash
          set -o xtrace
          /etc/eks/bootstrap.sh ${ClusterName} ${BootstrapArguments}
          /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal --exit-code $? \
                   --stack  ${AWS::StackName} \
                   --resource NodeGroup  \
                   --region ${AWS::Region}

  NodeGroup:
    Type: "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup"
    DependsOn: 
      - EksCluster
    #  - Vpc
    Properties:
      DesiredCapacity: !Ref NodeAutoScalingGroupDesiredCapacity
      LaunchConfigurationName: !Ref NodeLaunchConfig
      MaxSize: !Ref NodeAutoScalingGroupMaxSize
      MinSize: !Ref NodeAutoScalingGroupMinSize
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          PropagateAtLaunch: "true"
          Value: !Sub ${ClusterName}-MyNodeGroup-Node
        - Key: !Sub kubernetes.io/cluster/${ClusterName}
          PropagateAtLaunch: "true"
          Value: owned
      VPCZoneIdentifier: 
        - !Ref PublicSubnet1
        - !Ref PublicSubnet2
        #- !Ref PrivateSubnet1
        #- !Ref PrivateSubnet2        

    # CreationPolicy:
    #   AutoScalingCreationPolicy:
    #     MinSuccessfulInstancesPercent: !Ref NodeAutoScalingGroupDesiredCapacity
    #   ResourceSignal:    
    #     Count: !Ref NodeAutoScalingGroupDesiredCapacity
    #     Timeout: PT5M

    # UpdatePolicy:
    #   AutoScalingRollingUpdate:
    #     MaxBatchSize: "1"
    #     MinInstancesInService: !Ref NodeAutoScalingGroupDesiredCapacity
    #     PauseTime: PT5M

Outputs:
#   GatewayHostPublicIp:
#     Description: Gateway host public ip
#     Value: !GetAtt GatewayHost.PublicIp

  NodeInstanceRoleArn:
    Value: !GetAtt NodeInstanceRole.Arn

  EksClusterEndpoint:
    Description: EksCluster endpoint
    Value: !GetAtt EksCluster.Endpoint
```